# Localize time in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, timestamp, locale

I am working on an Android application. User can send post and can see each other's post, pretty much like Twitter. Here's a issue with the time.

When server serialized timestamp from DB and send as response, it responses a String like this: `2011-09-01 13:20:30+00:00"` Where I think the `+00:00` part is [UTC offset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).

I was wondering what's a good approach to parse this string to some time object in local time zone? so I can show it correctly on UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` has the capability of capturing your offset independently in a meaningful way. You want to translate the offset to a zone without explicitly specifying it to the `parser` instance.

Using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX");
try {
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Gives,

```
Thu Sep 01 18:50:30 IST 2011
```

[`joda`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) time library provides for an alternative resolution.

`DateTimeFormatter` is capable of parsing the format with `Z` added to the pattern and the parsed date is in the ***users default timezone***.

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
String date = "2011-09-01 13:20:30+00:00";

System.out.println(parser.parseDateTime(date));
System.out.println(parser.parseDateTime(date).toDate());
```

Gives,

```
2011-09-01T18:50:30.000+05:30
Thu Sep 01 18:50:30 IST 2011
```

You can pick any of the date formats above, modify it, further process it and use as part of your application.

Comment: I would agree with this answer though out of curiosity it would be nice to know who serializes the time. It's likely the same object will know to interpret it as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it into a date object and then format it with a SimpleDateFormatter based on the user's Locale.